# Switching python scripts in node.js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I am using a node server to run python scripts. I am using the Python shell package to run them and this works fine. Here it is in the `server.js` file that I am running:

```
app.get('/start/:fileName', function(req, res) {  
  let fileName = req.params.fileName;
  console.log(fileName)
  PythonShell.run(`./python_scripts/${fileName}`, function (err,results) {
    console.log('results ',results);
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('finished');
  });
});
```

In another file `main.js` I have the command:

```
function fetchStartEndpoint(fileName) {
  fetch(`/start/${fileName}`)
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
}``
```

And I call `fetchStartEndpoint` when a button is clicked.

This all works fine but I want to use multiple buttons to run multiple scripts. When I click the button a script runs, but when I click a different button to run a different script, the first one continues to run. I want it to end and run the second one. Is there a way to override the initial script and run the second one instead of other than restarting the server?

Answer (score 1):

I'm quickly browsing the readme at [python-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell) and it seems to me that calling `end` on the shell instance is the way to stop the running script:

### run(script, options, callback)

*This method is also returning the PythonShell instance.*

### .end(callback)

*Closes the stdin stream, allowing the Python script to finish and exit. The optional callback is invoked when the process is terminated.*

Based on that I would assume this can work:

```
// First button pressed ... 
var shell = PythonShell.run('script.py', function (err, results) {
   // script finished 
   shell = null
});

// Second button pressed ... 
if (shell) {

    shell.end(function() {
       // start second script ...
    })
}
```